# MongoDB / Discord.js - checking existence of a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I make a discord bot with MongoDB and I create a command to modify an article from my bot’s shop.
Before modifying a particular article, it must already be found in the database. Is it possible to find out if the name typed in the command exists in the database? If it does not exist, it returns an error message.

```js
    if(!oldName) return message.channel.send('<:croix:704272420873306165> You must indicate the name of your article')

    if(!newName) return message.channel.send('<:croix:704272420873306165> You must indicate the new name for your article')

    if() return message.channel.send('<:croix:704272420873306165> The name of the item doesn\'t exist.')

    await serverDB.set(message.guild.id, { $rename: { [ 'modules.SHOPECO.' + oldName ] : 'modules.SHOPECO.' + newName } })

    await serverDB.set(message.guild.id, { $set: { [ 'modules.SHOPECO.' + `${newName}.NAME` ] : newName } })

    message.channel.send("Good !")
```

Comment: Show us what have you done so far? And where you stuck?

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: @Syntle Yes, i'm using mongoose

Comment: @SamimHakimi I showed you my program above, the third condition is empty because that's the question I'm asking you

Comment: @Cyra please take a look at my answer.

Comment: @Syntle it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Model.findOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) for that. The reason why I'm not suggesting [`Model.exists()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.exists) anymore is because, according to the comments on this answer, you are trying to query multiple conditions and you can keep it simple using `findOne()`

```js
ArticleModel.findOne({ id: message.guild.id }, (err, res) => {
  if (res.modules.SHOPECO.includes(args[0]) return message.reply('that article already exists!')
})
```

Comment: https://zupimages.net/up/20/20/5g1o.gif

Instead of "articleName", I put `['modules.SHOPECO']` but it doesn't work (Cyra is the name of the article).

also taking into account the discord server id

Comment: is `SHOPECO` your model name? if so then do `SHOPECO.exists()`

Comment: No, I'm not talking about the model but the 'articlename', `serverDB.exists(message.guild.id, { ['modules.SHOPECO.' + oldName]: " " }` look at the link to the image I sent

Comment: Your query makes no sense, you need to use `exists()` like you'd use `find()` or `findOne()`. Why do you have `message.guild.id` in there? Give me an example of exactly what you're looking for under `modules.SHOPECO` and I'll help you with the query

Comment: If, it makes sense, each server has an id and therefore their own data, to know if it exists, the database must go into the data of the server in question, otherwise it will not work, that's why i put `message.guild.id`. On the photo, you see "Cyra: Object" in `modules.SHOPECO`, I just want to do when we type the command, args 0 if it appears or not in `modules.SHOPECO`. I can't explain it better

Comment: So is `id` above `name` in that screenshot the guild id?

Comment: The number series, yes

Comment: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: res.modules.SHOPECO.includes is not a function`